# PHP Parsing Array with Regex

Tags: php, arrays

I'm calling my remote API and getting this reply:

```
Array
(
    [TEST] => 1.1.1|Running
    [MODEL] => 4.91|Running
    [ENGING] => 2.4.37|Running
)
```

I want to Parse it and change it to:

```
Array
(
    [TEST] => [
        'version' => "1.1.1",
        'status' => 'Running'
    ]
    [MODEL] => [
        'version' => "4.91",
        'status' => 'Running'
    ]
    [ENGING] => [
        'version' => "2.4",
        'status' => 'Stop'
    ]
)
```

I tried a lot of ways,  and searched a lot on Google but didn't find a solution.

I want to split what's coming after the "|" to get the word after it.

Thanks!

Comment: Loop over the array and call `explode()` to split the value at the `|` character. Then replace the array element with the associative array that you want.

Comment: **I try a lot of ways**. Please show one of the ways you tried, then we'll help you fix it. We won't write it for you.

Comment: @Barmar no, there's always someone who will write it for them. :(

Comment: @miken32 I know that. I sometimes even post my canned "SO is not a code-writing service" comment after someone has written the code for free. The newbies need to learn.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Not much I can do about that. I suppose I could downvote the answer, but that just seems mean.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to get your desired result:

```
$response = array
(
    'TEST' => '1.1.1|Running',
    'MODEL' => '4.91|Running',
    'ENGING' => '2.4.37|Running'
);
$response = array_map(function ($v) { 
                          return array_combine(array('version', 'status'), explode('|', $v)); 
                                    },
                      $response);
print_r($response);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [TEST] => Array
        (
            [version] => 1.1.1
            [status] => Running
        )    
    [MODEL] => Array
        (
            [version] => 4.91
            [status] => Running
        )    
    [ENGING] => Array
        (
            [version] => 2.4.37
            [status] => Running
        )    
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/UgZcA)

Comment: Thanks!!!, you the best! but i found my issue, some service didn't reply with Version, so this what  was wrong. thanks again!